# Odoo 16. Mostrar una vista luego de ejecutar una función a través del menú

Tags: odoo

estoy realizando un proyecto en Odoo 16 y tengo esta duda, espero me puedan ayudar, tengo este botón en el menú:

```
        <record model="ir.actions.server" id="report_report_function">
            <field name="name">report_report_function</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_report_report"/>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">model.get_data_for_tree_view()</field>
        </record>
```

que al darle click me ejecuta esta función:

```
    @api.model
    def get_data_for_tree_view(self):
        records = self.search([])
        records.unlink()
        
        records = self.create([
            {'company': 'Company 1', 'month': 'january', 'total': '200'}, 
            {'company': 'Company 2', 'month': 'january', 'total': '300'}, 
            {'company': 'Company 3', 'month': 'january', 'total': '120'}
        ])

        action = {
            'name': 'Data from Method',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'view_type': 'tree',
            'res_model': 'report.report',
            'target': 'current',
            'view_id': self.env.ref('myapp.report_report_view_tree').id,
        }
        return action
```

y esta es la vista:

```
        <record id="report_report_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">report.report.view.tree</field>
            <field name="model">report.report</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="" create="false" edit="false">
                    <field name="company"/>
                    <field name="month"/>
                    <field name="total"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

pero no me está visualizando la vista, se queda en la vista actual y se que ejecuta la función ya que se actualizan los datos de la BD e incluso le pongo un print() y lo muestra en la consola, pero no carga la vista, me puede decir alguien qué tengo mal?????

Comment: Debes poner `action = model.get_data_for_tree_view()` en el xml del menú para que odoo sepa que estás retornando una vista.

Comment: Gracias, por responder, llevaba ya bastante tiempo rompiéndome la cabeza